# Show loading screen only once per session

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage, loading, session-storage

I am creating a “pseudo loading screen” which will display a full page div over the homepage once the page is opened and will disappear after a few seconds.

What I need to figure out is how to prevent this loading screen from showing after a user has clicked to another page on the site and then back to the home page (either using the back button or an anchor link back home).

Essentially I need the loader to only be shown the first time the user visits the website during the session, and only ever again during subsequent sessions.

(It would also be ideal if the loading screen was hidden when the home page is refreshed and if the loading screen appeared if the user begins their session on a page other than the homepage)

My best guess is that this will be achieved using localStorage but I’m new to JS so any suggestions on how to get this working would be great!

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, you can utilize the `sessionStorage` property of the `window` object. After showing the loading screen you can save this info in `sessionStorage`. For example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('shown', true);
```

And when the page is rendered you can check if the loading screen has been shown:

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('shown')) showScreen();
```

A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores. You can read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)